# wxWidgets PostNcDestroy Equivalent

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I am converting some legacy code from MFC to wxWidgets. 
The menu system I am converting uses static factory methods to create the dialogs and `postNcDestroy` to delete the `this` pointer and perform other cleanup.

What is the best way to do this cleanup in wxWidgets?

the class definition is pretty standard `CDialogEx` with the addition of

```
//some static vars
static bool m_bOpen;
...

//factory method
static void Showdlg(CCustomDlg* pParent);
virtual void PostNcDestroy() { m_bOpen = false; ... delete this; }
```

the implementation is

```
void CCustomDlg::Showdlg(CCustomDlg* pParent)
{
    m_bOpen = true;
...
    CCustomDlg*pDlg = new CCustomDlg(pParent);
    pDlg->Create(pParent);
    pDlg->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
}
```

Comment: Do you mean `postNcDestroy` ?

Comment: @RichardCritten yes sorry

Comment: @jhbh, could you post some code you use in that message handler? That way it will be easier to give a suggestion. Also PostNcDestroy message is mpt handled by wxWidgets.

Comment: @Igor sure. Ive added some code to hopefully give an idea of whats going on. basically the static method news up a dialog and this dialog is then responsible for deleting itself whenit is closed. I just don't know enough about wxWidgets to know where cleanup should go.

Comment: @jhbh, look at the dialogs sample in wxWidgets distribution. It looks like you just displays the dialog as non-modal. Sample contains the code that will show you how to make it work with wxWidgets. If you have any questions after that, don't hesitate to ask. If you already looked at the sample - just ask what you didn't understand.

Comment: @Igor thanks man. that did the trick for me. I didn't realize the source was available. I'm too used to just having headers and a lib. Thanks again!

Comment: @jhbh, that's why there is an open-source library. Also, keep in mind - it is always better to compile the library yourself than using the pre-compiled version.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why you need the m_bOpen variable, but I assume you have your reasons.  The roughly equivalent wxWidgets stuff would be something like the following.  Declaration:

```
class CCustomDlg : public wxDialog
{
    private:
        static bool m_bOpen;

    public:
        CCustomDlg( wxWindow* parent, 
            wxWindowID id = wxID_ANY, 
            const wxString& title = wxEmptyString, 
            const wxPoint& pos = wxDefaultPosition, 
            const wxSize& size = wxDefaultSize, 
            long style = wxDEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE );
        ~CCustomDlg();
};
```

Implementation:

```
bool CCustomDlg::m_bOpen=false;

CCustomDlg::CCustomDlg( wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id, const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size, long style ) : wxDialog( parent, id, title, pos, size, style )
{
    m_bOpen=true;
...
}

CCustomDlg::~CCustomDlg()
{
    m_bOpen=false;
}
```

You can then create a modal version of the dialog as follows (assuming this code is being called from the code for the main application form):

```
CCustomDlg dlg(this);
dlg.ShowModal();
```

wxWidgets will handle all of the cleanup for the dialog when the dlg object goes out of scope.  You can also check the return value of ShowModal() to see if it is wxID_OK when on OK button is pressed, wxID_CANCEL when a cancel button is pressed, or some other value you supply yourself with a call to EndModal() in your code for CCustomDlg.

If you want a nonmodal version of the dialog, things are a little trickier.  In that case you would create a pointer to the dialog using new, call Show() instead of ShowModal(), and then need to call Destroy() at an appropriate later time when the dialog is no longer needed.  See the "Modal and Modeless" section of [this page](http://file:///C:/Development/wxWidgets-3.1.0/docs/html/classwx_dialog.html) for more information.

Comment: (s)he is using the variable to indicate if the dialog is open. its a modeless dialog, so that's what it is.

Comment: Ok, I get it now.  Probably the easiest thing to do would be to use a modal version if possible.  If it must be nonmodal, the easiest thing is to create an instance in the main frame's constructor, call Show() as needed while the main frame is running, and call Destroy() in the main frame's destructor.  In that case, the IsShown() method is probably a suitable replacement for the static m_bOpen variable.  If however, you want the dialog to exist only sometimes, things will be trickier as I mentioned.